# How to this task in Hadoop? (real time public-subscribe sharing queue)

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, hdfs, distributed-computing

I have three threads a,b,c

a&b: Looping, each time output a line.

Both a and b writes their data to c.

c: Read the data from a and b, and do some processing.

I want to implement this task on top of HDFS. So A and B writes their data to HDFS, and C read the data from it.

So firstly I came up with an idea that each time of the loop, A writes to a new file in folder "/a-c". e.g. in the first loop, A output a line to a file /a-c/0.txt, next time of the loop, /a-c/1.txt,etc.

The reader C, read files from /a-c and /b-c, after reading, delete the file.

This is proved to work, but extremely low efficiency.

Question:

Is there any other way to create a queue like structure on top of HDFS(or channel) so that there is a public channel P_QUEUE, where A & B can write their data to, and C can read from.

(Remember these things happen concurrently.)

Or, alternatively, any other way to implement this task on top of HDFS????????

Comment: It is just about how to make Hdfs process in a more stream way rather than batch way.

Comment: why do you need to use HDFS? I would say it is really poor fit for this task. Something like Kafka will work much better.